# React Native: How can i fetch Data instant before rendering Screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I tried it with this method

```html
useEffect(() => {
    async function getUserData() {
      var userData = await firebase.firestore().doc("ingredients/" + user.uid).get();
      var labels = []
      userData.data().ingredients.forEach(ingredient => {
        labels.push(ingredient.label)
      })
      setUserIngredients(labels)
      setUserRecipes(userData.data().recipes)
    }
    getUserData()
    fetchRecipes(userIngredients)
  }, [])
```

but it does not load when I use the app I need to save the file on my computer before it fetches the data. I'm using expo to debug the app on my smartphone. I want it to fetch the data when I go to the screen or when my app is starting

Comment: you can add loader since you don't know how much time it will take to fetch data, and when data is fetched then remove the loader.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loader when data is being fetching and hide it when data is fetched !
`also`  if you want instant data fetch even before rendering screen ,then it is not the good approach if you really want it then do data fetch in custom constructor!

i.e

```
  const [constructorHasRun, setConstructorHasRun] = useState(false);
```

and call fetch API in this constructor

```
 const constructor = () => {
    if (constructorHasRun) return;
    // fetch API   
    setConstructorHasRun(true);
  };
```

Hope You wants it and helped !

Comment: and where do i call the constructor method to use it before render ?

Comment: const constructor = () => {
    if (constructorHasRun) return;
    else {
      getUserData();
      fetchRecipes();
      setConstructorHasRun(true);
    }
  };

Comment: this is my code now but it doesnt get the ingredients from the database and it doesnt fetch the data before render. sry im new to react

Comment: just put this constructor in your functional component and call it right away by ```constructor()```

Comment: the getUserData() function does not put the ingredients from the firebase instant into the userIngredients. how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

For these cases, I recommend saving data in Redux states is helping your app seems fast and you can access it when you need it.
Also, if you don't use Redux, you can save your data in SQLite because it seems your data about recipes, and update your data in the splash screen.
That's just another solution...